# Parse Cloud Code in Java and Calling the code in Swift

Tags: java, ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement this code using java and the cloud code option from Parse.

Does anyone know how to implement this code in Java and then correctly call it from my function using PFCloud?

```
//Search for submissions & groups
var findUsersInGroupData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "GameInfo")
findUsersInGroupData.whereKey("Group", equalTo:groupName)
findUsersInGroupData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
  (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
    if error == nil{
      for object in objects{
        let usersInGroup:PFObject = object as PFObject
        self.timelineData.addObject(usersInGroup)
        var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Submissions")
        findTimelineData.whereKey("User", equalTo: usersInGroup.objectForKey("User"))
        findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
          (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
             if error == nil{
               for object in objects{
                 let submission:PFObject = object as PFObject
                 self.timelineData.addObject(submission)
               }

               let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
               self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
               self.tableView.reloadData()
             }
         }
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I just do not know enough java to know who to implement a function such as this. Looking for some help

Comment: You are at wrong place. ;)